# How do you specify the UTM zone in mapshaper?

Tags: coordinate-system, mapshaper

I have a GeoJSON file containing boundary data for Norwegian administrative units called fylker. The original source of the data (GeoNorge) identifies the coordinate system as EUREF89 UTM zone 33, 2d.  I need it in WGS84.

I'm trying to use [mapshaper](https://mapshaper.org/) to do the conversion.  I load up the file, open the console and execute the command `-proj from=utm wgs84`. It appears to work; the shapes displayed get slightly squashed, but I think that's normal.  After that I simplify the shapes a bit and export a fresh GeoJSON.

But when I open the new GeoJSON file in [geojson.io](https://geojson.io/), the shapes are offset quite a bit -- hovering in the ocean about half way between Norway and Iceland.  I'm not a GIS expert by any means, but it looks like it's interpreting the source data as if it were in UTM zone 30 or 31, instead of UTM zone 33.

I tried `-proj from=utm33 wgs84`, but it failed because it didn't recognize `utm33` as a valid projection. The documentation doesn't mention this.

So how do I tell it that this data is in UTM zone 33?  Or is there something else I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [mapshaper docs](https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper/wiki/Command-Reference#-proj) specify using a *Proj.4 string, EPSG code or alias*. "utm33" is none of those, I don't know where you got that from.

Try (just going from the docs here, I can't actually test):

```
-proj from=25833 crs=4326
```

Or:

```
-proj from=EPSG:25833 crs=EPSG:4326
```

25833 and 4326 are the EPSG codes for [ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N](https://epsg.io/25833) and [WGS84](https://epsg.io/4326)

Comment: I just tried it, and that works.  Thank you; I am accepting this answer.

In related news, apparently you can specify additional parameters by passing a Proj4 string in quote marks, e.g. `-proj from='+proj=utm +zone=33' wgs84`, a fact that the author revealed when I posted a bug about this.  The wiki entry has been updated to include this information.

Comment: That's pretty standard commandline syntax for parameters with spaces.  I just used the epsg code as it's shorter.